# index.html is not read from the intended directory

Tags: fedora, documentroot

I am trying to set up a virtual host on a Fedora 18 installation. This is on Rackspace.

```
Following is my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (I deleted all the comment lines for brevity):

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

EnableSendfile on

Include conf.d/*.conf
```

Here is my /etc/httpd/conf.d/00-rails.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.myinstall.com
    DocumentRoot /home/test/public
    <Directory /home/test/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride all
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my /home/test/public I added an index.html file with the following in it:

```
<h3>This is a test page</h3>
```

The problem is that when I go to test.myinstall.com, I see the Fedora test page, as opposed to the message in index.html

When I do apachectl -S, here's what I get:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server test.myinstall.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/00-rails.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost test.myinstall.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/00-rails.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost test.myinstall.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/00-rails.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

Additional info:

Here's my /etc/hosts file:

```
#this is the IPv6 address
#I used xxx to mask the real address
2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:d0a5:ff04:ab82 test.myinstall.com
#this is the externally accessible IP address
64.49.xxx.xx    test.myinstall.com
#this is the internal Rackspace IP address
10.xxx.xx.xx    test.myinstall.com
```

Any ideas?

## apache error log:

```
[Tue Apr 23 23:28:25.617954 2013] [suexec:notice] [pid 25527] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[ 2013-04-23 23:28:26.0266 25531/7f638fcdd740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:554 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.25527/generation-0/request.socket
[ 2013-04-23 23:28:26.0432 25536/7f4251e71800 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:272 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.25527/generation-0/logging.socket
[Tue Apr 23 23:28:26.084527 2013] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 25527] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[ 2013-04-23 23:28:27.0253 25550/7f5362aa7740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:554 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.25527/generation-1/request.socket
[Tue Apr 23 23:28:27.041518 2013] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 25527] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[ 2013-04-23 23:28:27.0498 25555/7f21c5883800 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:272 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.25527/generation-1/logging.socket
[Tue Apr 23 23:28:27.064938 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25527] AH00163: Apache/2.4.4 (Fedora) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.0.rc6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 23 23:28:27.065043 2013] [core:notice] [pid 25527] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Apr 23 23:28:33.851049 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 25565] [client 66.xxx.141.202:2300] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/test/public/
[Tue Apr 23 23:28:35.637170 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 25565] [client 66.xxx.141.202:2300] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/test/public/
[Tue Apr 23 23:50:49.520907 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 25567] [client 66.xxx.141.202:56561] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/test/public/
[Tue Apr 23 23:50:49.744630 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 25567] [client 66.xxx.141.202:56561] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/test/public/favicon.ico
```

Permissions for /home/test:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 test apache 4096 Apr 10 05:17 app
drwxr-xr-x. 2 test apache 4096 Apr 10 20:11 public
```

Comment: So what was logged in the Apache `error_log`?

Comment: See my edits to the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as shown in your error log is that you don't have permission to read the `/home/test/public` directory.

```
[Tue Apr 23 23:28:33.851049 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 25565] [client 66.xxx.141.202:2300] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/test/public/
```

The reason for this is that you have denied access to it:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

While you have a separate `<Directory /home/test/public>` entry, it doesn't allow access. It seems to have the old Apache 2.2-style `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` directives. These have no effect in Apache 2.4, and have been replaced with the `Require` directive.

To resolve the issue, allow access to the directory. Remove the old directives and replace them with the new one:

```
<Directory /home/test/public>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: This solved the problem